# C http server get data array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to set up a simple webserver in C.
The server reads a request into a `char`, example request:

```
GET /?var1=val1&var2=val2 HTTP/1.1
```

**How can I format this `char` so that I can retreive the values like an array?**

Something in this format:

```
const char *requestData[2][80];
//
    Some code filling up requestData[][] with the url parameter values
//
requestData[0][0] -> val1
requestData[1][0] -> val2
```

I have tried some things like while loops combined with `strcmp()`, but these attempts seem inefficient, what would be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Try using `strtok()`.

Comment: Perhaps read a C primer?